# AngularJS RxJS Observable on message event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, rxjs

We open a Facebook window for authentication using,

```
let fbWindow = window.open(ourUrl);

// ourUrl redirects to Facebook login
```

and subscribe to `message` event, using:

```
let source = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message');
        var subscription = source.subscribe(
          function (e) {
            console.log('data', e);
          },
          function (err) {
            console.log('Error: %s', err);
          },
          function () {
            console.log('Completed');
          });
        return subscription;
```

The message event is never received. The same code in AngularJS 1 using

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(e) {});
```

Always receives the message event once the Facebook authentication is successful.

What's the difference, `fromEvent` is supposed to mimic event listeners on document events.

Comment: Its hard to tell without a more complete code example. Where are you invoking `open` with relation to the `subscription`?

Comment: Yes. We invoked commented and waited on the subscription

Comment: I am still not understanding, could you edit your code example to show the flow?

Comment: Edited. Note we open ourUrl which is on our server. The server redirects to Facebook login.